# Can I deploy a Windows Phone 7.1app from VS2010 to a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have been developing applications for Windows Phone 7.1 using VS2010 on Windows 7.  I have just picked up a Nokia Lumia 920 (Windows Phone 8), but do not seem to be able to deploy the app to the phone.

Has anybody been able to deploy from VS2010 to a Windows Phone 8 device, and are there any tricks to it?

Comment: I'm still waiting for my WP 8 device to test. :( Anyway, I suggest you to use the XAP deployer (Application Deployment) tool and try

Comment: No go, unfortunately.  Seems that WP7 deployment requires the phone to be connected through Zune, and WP8 devices don't connect to Zune.  Maybe there's no way to do this short of installing Windows 8 / VS2012, which is not something a Government department is going to do lightly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. There is no alternatives available to achieve this in VS 2010

Comment: +1. Only way is to install VS 2012. You can have there a wp7 project, which would run fine on wp8 either.